# AD FS fails, logging event ID 364

Tags: adfs2.0

After a failed attempt to change the service account for AD FS in a dev environment, I'm getting the following error in the logs when I try to log in to a relying party application:

> Microsoft.IdentityServer.Configuration.ReadServiceConfigFailedException:
>   MSIS2001: Configuration service URL is not configured. --->
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.PolicyModel.Client.StorageAuthorizationException:
>   ADMIN0120: The client is not authorized to access the endpoint
>   net.tcp://localhost:1500/policy. The client process must be run with
>   elevated administrative privileges.

The AD FS service is running under the Network Service account, as is the AD FS IIS app pool. I've checked SPNs and they correspond with what is configured in the other environments.

What else could I have misconfigured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by re-running the ADFS configuration wizard. (Program Files\Active Directory Federation Services 2.0\FsConfigWizard.exe) and specifying that it should recreate the database. That required me to recreate the relying party trusts and custom attribute stores. Fortunately, I had them all scripted via PowerShell so it wasn't too bad.